# How to design and maintain multiple live code stream on single git repository

Tags: git, git-branch-sculpting

I have a project with two live versions (new version is not backward compatible therefore two completely separate code stream). Question: how should I design git (looking for best practice):

1) Have two separate Master and Develop branches for both versions in same repo (don't want to have separate repo)

2) Use git tags (not families with this much and don't know if this'll work with Bamboo build server)

3) Other options..

Any help in this field will be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd switch to two separate repos to every unrelated/disconnected Project.

Any way the only idea perhaps is usefull for you is créate a new orphan branch for one of the "reports":

> git checkout --orphan newbranch

You can start this new branch from the starting point you want.  See options in manual.

This behaviour let you to maintain two disconnected branches.  Anyway you cannot have two 'master' branches (with the same exact name).

My 2c.